# Saving a file download directly in predefined folder without confirmation

Tags: servlets, save, download

I'm trying to download a file using a servlet. If I make use of Content Disposition response Header,an open/save dialog box would appear. Is there a way that I could save the file directly to a folder instead of selecting the destination from the dialog box. I would need this approach since. the file is being downloaded from a batch rather than a webapp.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to download from a sharepoint server and store it in my batch server, since in the batch we would manipulate the file contents.

Comment: @home I tried to retrieve the response of the file by means of streams , but the details I retrieved are rather not the intended ones. Hence I resorted to downloading the file and then reading it. Probably I recheck with the admin about the URL that I'm making use of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were possible, any arbitrary website would theoretically be able to silently write malware to visitor's disk without any notification. Would you as being the visitor appreciate it?

I don't think so.

It's **fortunately** not possible to write anything to visitor's disk without confirmation by standard HTTP/HTML means. The world wide web would have looked very different.

If you have really a hard head in this, then your best bet is creating a signed(!) Java applet for the job of file downloading and saving. You see this also often on those "large" websites as so-called "Download Managers" which can easily annoy endusers. Again, do this only if you have *really* a hard head in this.

Comment: I get it. I will resort to other means , such as reading through streams and writing it to a file. Thank you.

Comment: By the way ... I'm not sure what you were trying to tell there in your first comment about streaming, but I vaguely suspect that you somehow expected that you would be able to use `FileOutputStream` referring a path of visitor's local disk file system. I'd only like to note that this is again another major misconception of the basics. Such an approach would only work when both the client and server runs at physically the same machine, as would occur only when you're locally developing.